# How to disable multiselection on Treeview in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I've a **Treeview** widget, and I need only one row/item to be selected at a time. I've been reading [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview), but I can't find any property or method to do so, nor I've found something useful on SO.

Is it posible? How to?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is [a bit higher up the page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#id7):

> selectmode
>
> Controls how the built-in class bindings manage the selection. One of “extended”, “browse” or “none”. If set to “extended” (the default), multiple items may be selected. If “browse”, only a single item will be selected at a time. If “none”, the selection will not be changed.
>
> Note that the application code and tag bindings can set the selection however they wish, regardless of the value of this option.

Setting `selectmode="browse"` should give the behavior you're asking for.

Comment: What I needed to use was `selectmode="none"` and your answer solved my problem which was a similar but different question than OP's.